# make the Text of Textbox invisible

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Is it possible some how to make the `Text` of the `Textbox` invisible or to hide it so the user can't see it , yet it get's the input/keys from the user?

Comment: is this using WPF or winforms?

Comment: Yes, simply don't assign it to the `Text` property. Then it's invisible.

Comment: Don't even bother with a textbox. Set the `KeyPreview` property of the form to true and handle the `KeyPress` event there.

Comment: What's the real goal?

Answer (score 6):

It's better to rely on the built-in capabilities.
For instance, consider to use the [`TextBox.PasswordChar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: was abount to answer just that. setting this property to a single space does the trick

Answer (score 2):

You can set `ForeColor` = `BackColor`

Comment: @Izzy It's tagged as winforms, not WPF. Winforms is ForeColor.

Answer (score 0):

Paste in your `Properties` -> `Behavior` -> `PasswordChar` symbol you need, empty blanks works too.